# Audio data dumping to audio sink but no audio from speaker

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, speaker

I am using a Baytrail intel z3735 tablet. I am trying to run ubuntu 14.04/15.04 with linux kernel version 3.16/4.2.0. When I play an audio file the audio data is dumping to the audio sink but there is no audio coming from the speaker. I am able get the sound card detected as below...

```
sanj@sanj:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: bytrt5640 [byt-rt5640], device 0: Audio rt5640-aif1-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
sanj@sanj:~$
```

Audio Sink nodes :

```
sanj@sanj:~$ pactl list sinks
Sink #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.platform-byt-rt5640.analog-stereo
    Description: byt-rt5640 Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 99957 / 153% / 11.00 dB,   front-right: 99957 / 153% / 11.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 41350 /  63% / -12.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.platform-byt-rt5640.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = ""
        alsa.id = "Audio rt5640-aif1-0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "byt-rt5640"
        alsa.long_card_name = "byt-rt5640"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach"
        device.bus_path = "platform-byt-rt5640"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/80860F28:00/byt-rt5640/sound/card0"
        device.string = "hw:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "96000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "48000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "byt-rt5640 Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000)
    Active Port: analog-output-speaker
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Audio Source nodes :

```
sanj@sanj:~$ pactl list sources
Source #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.platform-byt-rt5640.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of byt-rt5640 Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.platform-byt-rt5640.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of byt-rt5640 Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "byt-rt5640"
        alsa.long_card_name = "byt-rt5640"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach"
        device.bus_path = "platform-byt-rt5640"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/80860F28:00/byt-rt5640/sound/card0"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.platform-byt-rt5640.analog-stereo
    Description: byt-rt5640 Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 93554 / 143% / 9.27 dB,   front-right: 93554 / 143% / 9.27 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = ""
        alsa.id = "Audio rt5640-aif1-0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "byt-rt5640"
        alsa.long_card_name = "byt-rt5640"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach"
        device.bus_path = "platform-byt-rt5640"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/80860F28:00/byt-rt5640/sound/card0"
        device.string = "hw:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "96000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "48000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "byt-rt5640 Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Ports:
        analog-input: Analog Input (priority: 10000)
    Active Port: analog-input
    Formats:
        pcm
sanj@sanj:~$
```

To test whether audio is coming to sink or not, I am using pulseaudio commands **paplay** and **parecord** from different terminals. Since source 0 is the source-monitor node for sink node 0, I captured audio from it.

```
sanj@sanj:~$ paplay Dhaakad.wav 
sanj@sanj:~$ parecord -d 0 > test.wav
```

Then I tested the captured audio file **test.wav** with audacity on a PC and it was playing fine. I am not able to figure out why the audio not coming from speaker. I also tried to change the audio settings with **alsamixer** but nothing worked out.

Comment: Try running alsa-info.sh script... It is available at this location  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo and share the dump

Comment: Hi Varun, I have uploaded the dump to this link  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx6uCNJzJ0beLWRFc18wRDU0SHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, I did not find much lead where I can pin point the problem... I can give few pointers . 

1)In the log you uploaded "Loaded ALSA module" is showing as NULL, this could be an issue, generally it shows the module which registered the SoundCard.I have verified on my  system also. 
2) When you do playback with aplay , please check the 
cat /proc/asound/cardx/pcmxp/sub0/status , it should not say closed, some  runtime data should be there.